# Most "natural way" of modeling teams as entities (ER modeling)

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have a question, that is rather vague, so this is why I am posting it, to maybe get some clarification. The question is:

> Suppose we want to model the teams to which a driver belongs. What is the most "natural" way of modeling the team (i.e. as entity set, relationship set, single-valued attribute, multi-valued attribute). Suppose that we want to model the leader of each team, the home country of each team and the name and birth of each driver.

My first reaction when I read this was: alright, we can say that the "Drivers" is an entity set containing attribute "name" and "birth date", "Teams" is another entity set containing the attributes "leader of the team" and "home country of the team" and then we just have a the relation "is part of" between the "Drivers" and "Teams". This seems the most natural way for me.

The dilemma came when I thought about modeling the team as a relationship from the entity "Drivers" to itself.

All in all, what is the most "natural way" of modeling the teams and solving this "problem"?